# Pandas: How to include double-quote marks when using read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file, `example1.txt`, with a list of search terms, some of which include double quotes. E.g.

```
Apple cider
"Bananas foster" v.2
Cherry comp*
"Pineapple" short-
"Peach" pie
```

However, `pd.read_csv('example1.txt', header=None, sep='\n', skipinitialspace=True, quoting=1)`, strips out the quote marks (which I'd like to be included):

```
Apple cider
Bananas foster v.2
Cherry comp*
Pineapple short-
Peach pie
```

I've tried playing around with the different parameters for `read_csv`, but have been struggling to find a way to include the quotes, as it seems all of the resources are focused on how to remove them, not include them. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `quotechar`:

```py
pd.read_csv('test.csv', quotechar="'", header=None, sep='\n', skipinitialspace=True)
Out[0]: 
                      0
0           Apple cider
1  "Bananas foster" v.2
2          Cherry comp*
3    "Pineapple" short-
4           "Peach" pie
```

Comment: You beat me to it, I posted the same answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

I know you are using Pandas, and I'm not entirely sure if they have something similar, however, using `csv.reader` allows you to specify a `quotechar`, which by default is `"`

Try the below code:

```py
file_stream = csv.reader(open('myFile.csv'), skipinitialspace=True, quotechar=None)
for row in file_stream:
    print (row)
```

Try that code and post back if that has your desired results.